# Embed a test for null in a single LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq, null, nullable

Let's start with a simple example class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Then create a list:

```
List<Foo> foos = new List<Foo>;
```

I would like to return a formatted price or "N/A" of one item in the list based on a date, so for example I could write:

```
Foo foo = foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Date == DateTime.Today);
string s = (foo != null) ? foo.Price.ToString("0.00") : "N/A";
```

**I would like to combine the above 2 lines *like* the following:**

```
string s = foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Date == DateTime.Today).Price.ToString("0.00") ?? "N/A";
```

However, this does not achieve what I want because if `(f => f.Date == DateTime.Today)` does not return a Foo then a `NullReferenceException` is thrown.

**Therefore, is it possible with LINQ to create just 1 statement  to either return the formatted price or "N/A"?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you filter first and then select, you can use the null coalescing operator (`??`) like so:

```
string price = foos.Where(f => f.Date == DateTime.Today)
                   .Select(f => f.Price.ToString())
                   .FirstOrDefault() ?? "N/A";
```

Answer (score 5):

One way would be to simply check if result of `FirstOrDefault` is null, before calling `ToString`:

```
var todayFoo = foos.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Date == DateTime.Today);
var s = todayFoo != null ? todayFoo.Price.ToString("0.00") : "N/A";
```

Another way would be to create an extension method for a coalescing operator which also accepts a projection delegate, something like:

```
public static class ObjectExt
{
    public static T2 Coalesce<T1, T2>(
         this T1 obj, Func<T1, T2> projection, T2 defaultValue)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return defaultValue;

        return projection(obj);
    }
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
var s = foos
         .FirstOrDefault(f => f.Date == DateTime.Today)
         .Coalesce(t => t.Price.ToString("0.00"), "N/A");
```

Comment: thank you - I really like the extension method, however, I just feel that Allon's solution is more succinct and importantly for me (although it wasn't a requirement) more versatile for other scenarios.

Comment: @Barry: I agree, Allon's solution is simpler. LINQ allows this because of its lazy execution, but you can use the extension method in other cases (any time you need to coalesce before accessing a property).

Comment: @Groo: Actually, it's not because of lazy evaluation - you can put `.ToArray()` after each method call to prevent lazy evaluation and it will still work. It's due to the set-based nature of the operations, where an empty set is still a set, and so projection on it will not throw a `NullReferenceException`. Nevertheless, your extension method is very useful.

Answer (score 2):

`string s = foos.Where(f => f.Date == DateTime.Today).Select(f => f.Price.ToString("0.00")).FirstOrDefault();`